# Filter HttpRequestValidationException Elmah Logs by IP Address

Tags: filter, ip-address, elmah

I've added this to the global.asax page to help me filter out errors from being logged onto elmah but that only filters any exception error that contains the HttpRequestValidationException. I am receiving these errors from McAfee scans. I was wondering if there was a way to check for an ip address, if the ip address matches that of McAfee, then do not log the error. I tried to do:

```
void ErrorLog_Filtering(object sender, ExceptionFilterEventArgs e)
{
    if (Server.HtmlEncode(Request.UserHostAddress) == "173.15.183.122" 
        && e.Exception.GetBaseException() is HttpRequestValidationException) {
        e.Dismiss();
    }
}
```

That isn't working for me. If there is a way to grab an ip address please let me know and what namespace I would need to add to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added this to my web.config file to check for certain ip addresses, which would help filter out what errors I do not want to log in my database.

```
<elmah>
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SQLiteErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ELMAH.SQLite" />
    <security allowRemoteAccess="yes" />
    <errorFilter>
      <test>
        <and>
          <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="500" type="Int32" />
          <regex binding="Context.Request.ServerVariables['REMOTE_ADDR']" pattern="((165.193.42.(6[7-9]|7[0-9]|8[0-6]|13[1-9]|14[0-9]|150))|(161.69.30.(13[6-9]|1[4-5][0-9]|16[0-7]))|(64.14.3.(196|21[4-9]|22[0-9]))|(64.41.168.(24[2-9]|25[0-4]))|(216.35.7.(9[8-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-6]))|(64.41.140.(9[8-9]|10[0-7]))|(161.69.14.(13[6-9]|1[4-5][0-9]|16[0-7])))$" type="String" />
        </and>
      </test>
    </errorFilter>
</elmah>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it in `ErrorLog_Filtering` (I also do it in `ErrorMail_Filtering`) like the OP was trying to do, this will work:

```
if(Context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "173.15.183.122") e.Dismiss()
```

I prefer using `.StartsWith("173.15.183")` as these services often use lots of IPs in that range (and I don't care too much if an error from someone else in that same block gets filtered if it was to ever happen)